# hardcode xml in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, force.com

im new to salesforce i want to embed(hard code) the xml code in vf page,when i m trying to do that im getting following error.

Compilation error: <apex:page> is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1

and this my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <response>
        <is_registered>yes</is_registered>
        <is_workinghour>yes</is_workinghour>
        <Lead>00Q9000000Kwe6IEAR</Lead>
        <CallID>04153c09-8018-4cba-b03e-cd98a80f30b0</CallID>
        <agent_number_count>3</agent_number_count>
        <agent_list>
        <agent id="1">
        <agent_number>2228241485</agent_number>
        <agent_code>0004</agent_code>
        </agent>
        <agent id="2">
        <agent_number>2228321017</agent_number>
        <agent_code>0003</agent_code>
        </agent>
        <agent id="3">
        <agent_number>9699850686</agent_number>
        <agent_code>0001</agent_code>
        </agent>
        </agent_list>
        </response>
</ApexPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce pages does not allow you to start markup with any tag except apex:page.
If you want to display an xml-markup on you page you can try:

```html
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" contentType="text/xml" standardStylesheets="false">
  <!-- YOUR XML CONTENT HERE-->
</apex:page>
```

Hope this help

Comment: it work but i need with xml tag like this   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: Responder answered that, you cannot start with <?xml.  You must start with <apex: page .....